# window.close() minimizes Chrome with a froze white popup window instead of closing a popup window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I wrote a Chrome extension that works pretty good on a PC. While testing it on a mac I'm getting some strange behaviour. 
In some of the cases I'm forcing a popup to close while keeping a window open. (again, works fine on Windows). Doing so on a mac will minimize Chrome completely to the Dock. If I'll open Chrome again there will be a white froze popup that won't close until a Chrome restart.

I've searched Chrominuim for a similar bug report but came back empty.

In order to reproduce it I've narrowed it down to this :

**test.js:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function ()
{
    window.close();  
});
```

**test.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <a>testing</a>
     </body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json:**

```
    {
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "None",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test",
    "default_popup": "test.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
    }
```

I've also tried doing something like this:

```
var popups = chrome.extension.getViews({ type: "popup" });
    if (popups.length != 0) 
    {
      var popUpTest = popups[0];
      popUpTest.close();
    }
```

But got the same result.

If i'll add this line:

```
setTimeout(function(){window.close()},1000);
```

instead of

```
window.close();
```

The pop up will close most of the times but seeing the popup for a second or so beats the purpose. It seems that the browser waits for the popup to appear before it can actually close it and if its not there it will get funky and will minimize it self. 
I've managed to go far as:

```
setTimeout(function(){window.close()},35);
```

But sometimes I can still see the popup and sometimes the browser will be minimized. Defiantly not a solution but maybe it can help with an idea to finding one.

Comment: You should file a new bug on http://crbug.com/new. You should also remove the "content_scripts" section, since I believe it'll inject the content script after DOMContentLoaded fires, so won't do anything, but it'll confuse whoever investigates your bug.

Comment: @JeffreyYasskin Content scripts are not injected in extension pages at all, so it can completely be removed. In fact, the permission section can also be removed as they're not relevant either.

Comment: @JeffreyYasskin I'll file a bug report eventually. Wanted to make sure that it's a bug I'm facing.

Comment: @RobW You are both right. I've updated my question and removed unnecessary code and also updated it with some new findings.

Comment: @Segev How about a workaround, where you minimize the popup and then close the window, if necessary take it behind the main window.

Comment: @Dev Thanks for the reply but that's not really a workaround. That's doing something completely different. I want the popup to keep acting like an extension popup. Not a window.

Answer (score -1):

Although this is definitely a bug in Chrome that should be reported, I would recommend switching to [`chrome.windows` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows). You can close the current window using the API like so:

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(window) {
    var windowId = window.id;
    chrome.windows.remove(windowId);
});
```

This is, of course, working on the assumption that the Window object returned by `chrome.windows.getCurrent()` *has* an id. This field is optional in the Window object, so it would be best to provide code earlier on (i.e., initial creation of the window) that specifies an id for that window.

Comment: I don't think the popup has a windowId. It's not defined as a window.

Comment: You should be able to define one if you create the popup using `chrome.windows.create()`. I know it's a huge pain to have to rewrite things using the `chrome.windows` API, but that appears to be the only solution at the moment. I've run into a lot of odd edge cases with Chrome's window management on OS X that have forced me to completely change my UI design before. Fingers crossed that they fix this soon!

Comment: Thanks. If i'll do that I'll create a window popup and not the standard popup I'll get after clicking the add on button and that's not what I'm after.